# How can you force chrome on linux to recalculate/re-render ":hover" styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux, google-chrome

I have a situation where javascript code causes DOM/style changes that in turn should cause the page to render differently due to a change in the element that is under the mouse.  A simple example is:

```
<style type="text/css">
#one {
    position: relative;
}
#two {
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
}
#one:hover #two {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#one').on('click', function() {
        $('#one').css('left', '100px');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="one">One
    <div id="two">Foo</div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7Ac/1/ - when you click "One" the elements move so that the ":hover" styling should no longer be applied, but they don't actually get updated until you move the mouse after the click.

Is there something I can do in the "click" binding to recalculate/re-render immediately?

**Update**: This appears to only affect chrome on linux.  So possibly a bug in chrome.  Still, if anyone has ideas about working around this it would be great to hear them.

Comment: It does get applied on Chrome.

Comment: Ah interesting, this appears to only affect Chrome on Linux.  Updated the question

Comment: Affects Chrome and Safari on OSX, iOS and Android as well. Not a huge issue but kind of annoying when using SPA frameworks and a mobile browser because there's no mouse movement at all on mobile so the hover state doesn't disappear until you click somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Could try doing it with css classes, instead of the `:hover` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/4tfYN/